# MySQL: Selecting MAX value and grouping

Tags: mysql

This is what I have now in my query:

```
+--------------------+-----------+------------+
| status             | entity_id | seconds    |
+--------------------+-----------+------------+
| Submitted          |       494 | 1352102400 |
| Accepted           |       494 | 1352275200 |
| In press/e-publish |       494 | 1352966400 |
| Rejected           |       520 | 1355817600 |
| Accepted           |       570 | 1352102400 |
+--------------------+-----------+------------+
```

I want it to look like:

```
+--------------------+-----------+------------+
| status             | entity_id | seconds    |
+--------------------+-----------+------------+
| In press/e-publish |       494 | 1352966400 |
| Rejected           |       520 | 1355817600 |
| Accepted           |       570 | 1352102400 |
+--------------------+-----------+------------+
```

In quasi-SQL:

```
SELECT status, entity_id, MAX(seconds) 
FROM foo
GROUP BY entity_id, seconds
```

The above quasi-SQL looks correct, but the "status" column value does not correspond to the correct row.  I get back something like the below:

```
+--------------------+-----------+------------+
| status             | entity_id | seconds    |
+--------------------+-----------+------------+
| Submitted          |       494 | 1352966400 |
| Rejected           |       520 | 1355817600 |
| Accepted           |       570 | 1352102400 |
+--------------------+-----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Untested, but should look something like this:

```
SELECT status, entity_id, seconds
FROM entities E
WHERE E.seconds == (
  SELECT MAX(E2.seconds)
  FROM entities E2
  WHERE E2.entity_id = E.entity_id
)
```

(Setting up a SQLfiddle for your question would give you a more tested answer :p )

Comment: Never heard of SQL Fiddle until now.  Fortunately the poster below me created the SQL Fiddle page for us (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6ab2/12) and I was able to test your query and it worked, except for the "==", of course. :)

Comment: Doh! That was a pretty silly mistake to make... (blush) Especially since I have the correct one three lines down.

Answer (score 3):

The below Query will give your expected Result.

```
SELECT max(maxsec), status, entity_id from 
(SELECT status, entity_id, MAX(seconds)  as maxsec
FROM table1
GROUP BY entity_id,status) a GROUP BY entity_id
```

Your schema created [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6ab2/10).

Comment: Thanks for creating the SQLFiddle page.  It is very helpful, and your query worked.